# How to inject object that has constructor parameters in Angular?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-dependency-injection

I'm very to Angular and I want to figure out how can I pass parameters to an object constructor that is being injected into a component.

Here is an example:

image-capture.service.ts

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
export class ImageCapture {

  constructor(
    private sdk: any,
    private videoSource: HTMLVideoElement,
    private cameraFeedback: HTMLCanvasElement) {}
}
```

image-scanner.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-document-scanner-component',
  templateUrl: './app-document-scanner-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-document-scanner-component.scss'],
})
export class ImageScannerComponent {

  @ViewChild('video') video!: ElementRef<HTMLVideoElement>;
  @ViewChild('cameraFeedback') feedback!: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  constructor(private imageCaptureService: ImageCapture) { }

}
```

in `image-scanner. component` i need to pass to injected object `ImageCapture` few constructor parameters one is SDK instance that is being imported and second two parameters are HTML DOM elements that I'm getting using `@ViewChild` decorator.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass paramaters to the constructor of the service, because your service is created on loading of the application. So when you use your service inside a component, the service is already instantiated.

A solution is to create a function in your service:

```
public initialize(sdk: any,videoSource: HTMLVideoElement,cameraFeedback: HTMLCanvasElement) {}
```

then you juste have to call this function, in the constructor of your component.

Comment: ok, thanks but does `useFactory` in the providers solve this issue? Where I can directly create a constructor with parameters?

Comment: @Andrew I think you can use `@Input` to pass objects to one component to another.

Comment: @Andrew useFactory will not help you, beacause you need to pass some parameters, that are available after your component initialization (ViewChild).

When you provide a service directly on your component, you have to do it on the '@Component' decorator, so properties of your component are not available.

Comment: @Soukyone but besides HTML elements, if I need to pass another object is it doable?